# error: method addOutcome in class OutcomesTable cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, jbehave, hamcrest

When I am trying to hamcrest matcher with jbehave outcome table I am getting below compile time error at the time of maven build.

"error: method addOutcome in class OutcomesTable cannot be applied to given types"

please refer below sample code.

```
public static <T> void method(T expected, T actual) {

        OutcomesTable outcomes = new OutcomesTable();
        List expectedList = (ArrayList)expected;
        List actualList = (ArrayList)actual;

        for(Object ExpObj : expectedList){
            outcomes.addOutcome("a success", actualList, containsInAnyOrder(ExpObj));
        }

        outcomes.verify();
}
```

please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This is a type error on the "addOutcome" function. Check that it's parameters are of the correct type.

Comment: Looking at the docs, the third parameter should be `org.hamcrest.Matcher<List>`... Double-check your `containsInAnyOrder` call, I think its argument's type is the culprit...

Comment: Thanks Minits97  for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBehave's generic function `public <T> void addOutcome(String description, T value, Matcher<T> matcher);` expects that you provide the same type for `T` in both parameters that use `T`. e.g. If you pass a `String value` in your second parameter, then you need to provide a `Matcher<String>` in the third parameter.

In your case, you pass a `List` as the 2nd parameter, but pass the result of `containsInAnyOrder(T... items)` function called with a single `Object`, which will not produce the desired instance of a `Matcher<List>` type.

I'm not pretty sure, what you are trying to do, but I think what you need is:

```
    outcomes.addOutcome("a success", actualList, Matchers.contains(ExpObj));
```

The Matcher `containsInAnyOrder(T... items)` does not really make sense for only one value, as there exists only one permutation(order) of one element in an array. :)

You can also make your code compile like this:

```
    outcomes.addOutcome("a success", actualList, Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(ExpObj)));
```

, but I think that's not what you need.

Hope I was clear, and could help.